# Unable to clone my Repository on windows while using cmd , powershell and github desktop same problem

Tags: git-clone, github-desktop

while using command prompt, powershell , and GitHub desktop to clone my repository i'm unable to access my  repository URL

following message display

C:\Users\NIRANJAN MANITHIYA> git clone https://github.com/ashusainioffcial/coursera-test.git
Cloning into 'coursera-test'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ashusainioffcial/coursera-test.git/': getaddrinfo() thread failed to start

i tried different types of urls and command all useless

Answer (score -1):

Start a new terminal and type-  git config --global --unset-all https.proxy

and then turn off your firewall protection from antivirus or windows firewall